# Why the css property "important" is not working?

Tags: html, css

This is my css element:

```css
html, body, div, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, p, blockquote, fieldset, input, abbr, article, aside, command, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, mark, meter, nav, output, progress, section, summary, time, #ariane, #ariane1, #ariane2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px none;
  outline: 0px none;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:decimal!important;">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

The problem:

The style of the element is applied instead of `list-style-type:decimal!important;` in spite of i put the property "!Important;"

When i inspect the element `ul` i find that the property `list-style-type: none;` is underlined and is checked but `list-style-type: decimal !important;` is just checked , but that is normal because of `!important`.

So why the numbers are not desplayed nor any think else? and why the numbers are displayed just when i unchecked `list-style-type: none;`?

Comment: The answer below is correct, but one thing to point out: Adding `!important` to an inline style is unnecessary as inline styles will *always* override whatever the stylesheet says.

Comment: @Mike Christensen: Not always - when the stylesheet has an `!important` and the inline style doesn't, that `!important` wins, and the only way to override that is to have an `!important` inline style.

Comment: @BoltClock - Ah yes, you're correct.  Just re-read the spec again..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial CSS is applying the list-style-type to both the UL and the LI, the over-ride is only applying to the UL. So the LI's remain set to the initial rule set in your CSS.